# Is it possible to keep redundant prefixes for an assembly instruction in NASM?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I need to test if a windows emulator correctly identifies and handles an instruction that is too long (more than 15 bytes long). I compile the code with NASM.
The only way I know of specifying an instruction that is too long is by adding prefixes to the instruction. Let's say I do the following:

```
rep O32 rep O32 rep O32 rep O32 rep O32 mov eax, [fs:0]
```

In this case, I should get a 16-byte-long instruction, since `mov eax, [fs:0]` is a 6-byte-long instruction, plus the 10 `O32` and `rep` prefixes equal 16 bytes.

At least that's the theory ... but when I compile this with NASM and disassemble the resulting binary, what I find is that the unnecessary prefixes got plucked from there: only 1 `rep` prefix stays and obviously the `fs` segment prefix. Thus, the total length of the instruction is reduced to just 7 bytes. I guess this is how it is supposed to work, but is there a way to make it so the instruction length actually grows beyond bounds?

Comment: Would the `db` directive before the instruction provide what you need ?

Comment: Most probably NASM would no generate a binary with a instruction with length > 15 bytes, this is the length limit of Intel for valid instruction. Instead you could make the binary yourself, write a valid instruction (anyone), and prepend 16 NOP instruction, when assembled the file replace the 0x90 bytes (NOP instruction) with the prefix, you want.

Comment: I'm not sure the `db` directive will do any good. My guess is it's also ignored by NASM if it's superfluous. I will try that anyway.
I also thought of editing the binary itself as a last resort.
Thanks for the answers.

Comment: NASM won't delete a data directive. It has no way of knowing if it's supposed to be data or part of an instruction.

Comment: Okay, at first I didn't understand what you meant by using the `db` directive, but now I got it and it works! For anyone who is curious, needs this and/or is as slow as me, here is an example that generates an instruction longer than 16 bytes in NASM:


`db 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66`
`mov ax, 1`
Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

You state that `mov eax, [fs:0]` is a 6-byte-long instruction. This implies that you're using 16-bit code. (32-bit code would have taken 7 bytes)

Thus `mov ax,1` will use 3 bytes. You've prepended 12 operand size prefixes. 
This totals up to 15 which is still perfectly legal. Therefore you've not yet tested your 'windows emulator'.

If the solution presented is 32-bit code then the total will be 16 bytes.

Just curious : did the emulator complain?

Comment: I'm using 32-bit, "normal" x86 code. `mov eax, [fs:0]` is 6-byte-long: 64 A1 00 00 00 00. I'm not sure what the 7th byte would be. `mov ax, 1` is 4-byte-long: 66 B8 01 00; oh and yeah, it did complain. The example I gave in my comment above indeed is 16 bytes long and it causes an exception. If I take away one of the 0x66 prefixes, it runs fine.